# Query to return Pokemon with highest attack by group

Tags: mysql

I have a database full of Pokemon Cards, and their attacks. I want to do a query to find the Pokemon that has the strongest attack by each type. I want the view to show just the name, type, and damage of the attack.

```
SELECT p2.MaxD, p2.Type, p1.name 
FROM Pokemon p1 
INNER JOIN ( SELECT type, MAX(damage) MaxD, pokemon_name FROM Attack GROUP BY Type )
p2 ON p1.type = p2.type AND p2.pokemon_name = p1.name
```

I have this code. It returns the highest damage but not the correct Pokemon. The Pokemon table doesn't have a damage field. I'm trying to get a grasp of joins.

Here is the structure:

Attack table has 4 fields: pokemon_name (the pokemon this attack belongs to), damage, name (name of the attack), and type (the type of pokemon this attack belongs to).

The Pokemon table has 3: HP, type (of the pokemon), and name (of the pokemon).

Comment: can you post the structures of your tables?

Comment: why do you need to join to `pokemon` table if you have already name on the `attack` table? is `pokemon_name` ID or the name of the pokemon?

Comment: Wow, I feel stupid. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really sure about your schema but I assumed that the `pokemon_name` of your `attack` table is really the name of the pokemon.

```
SELECT  a.*, c.*
FROM    Attack a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  type, MAX(damage) MaxD
            FROM Attack 
            GROUP BY Type 
        ) b ON a.Type = b.Type AND
                a.damage = b.MaxD
        INNER JOIN Pokemon c
            ON c.Name = a.pokemon_name AND
                c.Type = a.Type
```

the above query displays all field from `attack` table and `pokemon` table, but If you are really interested on the `name`, `damage` and `type` the you only do query on `attack` table

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    Attack a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  type, MAX(damage) MaxD
            FROM Attack 
            GROUP BY Type 
        ) b ON a.Type = b.Type AND
                a.damage = b.MaxD
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all you have to build select that select maximal damage for each type (you already have that):

```
SELECT type, MAX(damage) MaxD FROM Attack GROUP BY Type
```

Now, this won't have a good performance unless:

- type is `INT` (or `ENUM` or other numeric type)
- there's index on `type` or `type, damage`

You cannot select `pokemon_name` because MySQL doesn't guarantee that you'll get `pokemon_name` matching `MaxD` ([here's a nice answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/537235/1149736) on stackoverflow which already covers this issue).

Now you can select pokemon with that matching `pokemon_name`

```
SELECT p1.pokemon_name, p1.type, p1.damage
FROM Attack p1
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT type, MAX(damage) MaxD FROM Attack GROUP BY Type
) p2 ON p1.type = p2.type
     AND p1.damage = p2.MaxDamage
GROUP BY (p1.type, p1.damage)
```

The last `GROUP BY` statement makes sure that having multiple pokemons with the same attack damage won't cause multiple records for one `type,damage` pairs.

Again, you will achieve good performance by replacing `pokemon_name` with `pokemon_id`. Maybe you should google [`database normalization`](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=database%20normal%20forms) for a while [[wikipedia]](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization),[[first tutorial]](http://www.bkent.net/Doc/simple5.htm). You also may want to check [this Q&A](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/8334/why-should-i-create-an-id-column-when-i-can-use-others-as-key-fields) out, it provides nice overview of what does "relation table" mean.

Now you have correct `pokemon_name` (for your program sake, I hope you'll replace this with `pokemon_id`) and you may put it all together:

```
SELECT p1.pokemon_name, p1.type, p1.damage, p.*
FROM Attack p1
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT type, MAX(damage) MaxD FROM Attack GROUP BY Type
) p2 ON p1.type = p2.type
     AND p1.damage = p2.MaxDamage
INNER JOIN Pokemon p
     ON  p.pokemon_name = p1.pokemon_name
GROUP BY (p1.type, p1.damage)
```

---

#### Ideal example

In perfect world you're database would look like this:

```sql
-- Table with pokemons
CREATE TABLE `pokemons` (
    `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` VARCHAR(255),
    -- More fields
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)

-- This contains pairs as (1,'Wather'), (2, 'Flame'), ...
CREATE TABLE `AttackTypes` (
    `id`,
    `name` VARCHAR(255)
)

-- Create records like (1, 2, 3, 152)
-- 1 = automatically generated keys
-- 2 = id of pokemon (let say it's Pikachu :P)
-- 3 = type of attack (this say it's Electric)
-- 152 = damage
-- This way each pokemon may have multiple attack types (Charizard flame + wind)
CREATE TABLE `Attacks` (
    `id`,
    `pokemonID` INT NOT NULL, -- Represents pokemons.id
    `typeID` INT NOT NULL, -- Represents attack.id
    `damage` INT
)
```

*ID fields are **ALWAYS** `PRIMARY KEY`, `NOT NULL` and `AUTO_INCREMENT` in this example*

And the select from it, again get types first:

```sql
SELECT MAX(attack.damage) AS mDmg, attack.typeID
FROM attack
GROUP BY attack.typeID
```

Than get pokemon ID:

```sql
SELECT a.pokemonID, a.damage, a.typeID
FROM attack AS a
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT MAX(a.damage) AS mDmg, a.typeID
    FROM attack AS a
    GROUP BY a.typeID
) AS maxA
    ON a.typeID = maxA.typeID
        AND a.damage = mDmg
GROUP BY (a.typeID)
```

And once you've covered all that you may actually select pokemon data

```sql
SELECT aMax.pokemonID as id,
    aMax.damage, 
    p.name AS pokemonName,
    aMax.typeID AS attackTypeID,
    t.name AS attackType

FROM (
    SELECT a.pokemonID, a.damage, a.type
    FROM attack AS a
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT MAX(a.damage) AS mDmg, a.type
        FROM attack AS a
        GROUP BY a.type
    ) AS maxA
        ON a.type = maxA.type
            AND a.damage = mDmg
    GROUP BY (a.type)
) AS aMax

INNER JOIN pokemons AS p
    ON p.id = aMax.pokemonID

INNER JOIN AttackTypes AS t
    ON t.id = aMax.typeID
```

#### Performance hints:

- you may add field `MaxDamage` into `AttackTypes` (which would be calculated by stored procedure) and will save you one level of nasted query
- all `ID` fields should be `PRIMARY KEY`s
- index on `Attacks.typeID` allows you to quickly get all pokemons capable of that type of attack
- index on `Attack.damage` allows you to quickly find strongest attack
- index on `Attack.type, Attack.damage` (two fields) will be helpful when finding max value for each attack
- index on `Attack.pokemonID` will make look up `pokemon -> attack -> attack type name` faster