# Find current/future day

Tags: mysql, date

### I have this table:

```
ID      dayNum      dayName     eventTypeID     
-------------------------------------------
1       4           Wednesday   1
2       7           Saturday    1
```

For an `eventTypeID` I want to select the row that contains the future or current day. Today is **Thursday**, so how can I return the row where `dayName` is Saturday?

I just need an `AND` statement for the below query:

```
SELECT      *
FROM        `events`
WHERE       `eventTypeID` = 1
AND         ??
```

### dayNum:

The `dayNum` field is the index for each day, where Monday = `1`, and Saturday = `7`.

If you can come up with an answer to this, just hard code today's day number as `5` (Thursday). I already have the logic to get today's `dayNum`, and it's not really relevant to the question.

Comment: It sounds like what you want to do is order the grouping so that a specific row is returned for each group. This will involve a subquery and not just an order by. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/537223/mysql-control-which-row-is-returned-by-a-group-by

Comment: Thanks, saved me some time. I edited the question.

Comment: `and dayNUM >= DAYOFWEEK(NOW())`

Comment: @AgRizzo That only works if there are multiple days for every event, otherwise it could be less than.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would sort by the "difference", then limit 1 like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM events
ORDER BY MOD(dayNum - DAYOFWEEK(NOW()) + 7, 7)
LIMIT 1
```

You will need to MOD 7 so if the current day is 7, the next nearest one should be 1 which is equivalent to (-6 MOD 7). There is an extra `+ 7` on there because MySQL seems to like to keep negative numbers negative after a modulo.

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7ec55/11)