# Grouping into interval multiple columns

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I have a MySql table like this:

```
+-------+---------------------+---------------------+------------+------------+
| id    | starttime           | endtime             | startv     | endv       |
+-------+---------------------+---------------------+------------+------------+
| 66612 | 2018-01-15 17:14:00 | 2018-01-15 17:14:59 | 0.01       | 1.002      |
| 66611 | 2018-01-15 17:13:00 | 2018-01-15 17:13:59 | 5.002      | 0.211      |
| 66610 | 2018-01-15 17:12:00 | 2018-01-15 17:12:59 | 1.001      | 2.011      |
| 66609 | 2018-01-15 17:11:00 | 2018-01-15 17:11:59 | 0.678      | 0.751      |
| 66607 | 2018-01-15 17:10:00 | 2018-01-15 17:10:59 | 0.201      | 1.752      |
```

I can grouping into interval of 5 minutes within a time range with:

```
SELECT * from activation
GROUP BY UNIX_TIMESTAMP(starttime) DIV 900
ORDER BY starttime DESC;
```

My current output is:

```
| 2018-01-15 17:10:00 | 2018-01-15 17:10:59 | 0.201      | 1.752      |
```

This give me a table grouped by starttime and the correct "startv" (0.201 in the table), what I need is join this with a column that contains the "endv" value that matching the last value of the group (the last "endtime" 1.002) instead of 1.752 with the correct "endtime" like:

```
+---------------------+---------------------+------------+------------+
| starttime           | endtime             | startv     | endv       |
+---------------------+---------------------+------------+------------+
| 2018-01-15 17:10:00 | 2018-01-15 17:14:59 | 0.201      | 1.002      |
```

Comment: So If I understand correctly, you want `startv` from the earliest row in the group, and `endv` from the latest row in the group?

Comment: @Jerry - It seems that everything starting with *start* should be from first and *end* - from last.

Comment: 66607 startv and 66612 endv, 
apologize for the confusion :)

Comment: You actually wrote your question very well. I just fumbled the reading. :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/537223/mysql-control-which-row-is-returned-by-a-group-by might give you the answer you need, and it not it, in turn, links to more info.

Comment: Thank you, I'm going to take a look

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write a subquery that gets the first and last timestamps in each group, then join with those to get the corresponding `startv` and `endv`.

```
SELECT r.starttime, r.endtime, afirst.startv, alast.endv
FROM (SELECT MIN(starttime) as starttime, MAX(endtime) AS endtime
      FROM activation
      GROUP BY UNIX_TIMESTAMP(starttime) DIV 300) AS r
JOIN activation AS afirst ON afirst.starttime = r.starttime
JOIN activation AS alast ON alast.endtime = r.endtime
ORDER BY r.starttime DESC
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9a266/7)

And for 5-minute intervals you should be dividing by `300`, not `900` (that's 15 minutes).

Comment: Thank you, but with more entries it give me wrong results, seems not to group them every 5 
[demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9a266/1)

Comment: @Captain also note that you divide with 900 (that is 15 minutes).

Comment: @Captain I forgot to use `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()`.

Comment: @Oops sorry for intervals confusion, here was late night! :)
Thank you for the answer!